# Loop based on tag in HTML document

Tags: html, python-3.x, loops, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract certain details from articles which are combined in an html file. The html file will consist of 1000s of articles so trying to automate the extraction using BeautifulSoup. For the first article I can get it to extract but do not seem to get it to automatically move on to the next article. This is how the html looks like:

```
        <DOCFULL> -->
          <br/>
          <div class="c0">
           <p class="c1">
            <span class="c2">
             2 of 4 DOCUMENTS
            </span>
           </p>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div class="c0">
           <br/>
           <p class="c1">
            <span class="c2">
             The New York Times
             <br/>
            </span>
    ...
        </DOCFULL>

    ...
        <DOCFULL> -->
          <br/>
          <div class="c0">
           <p class="c1">
            <span class="c2">
             1 of 4 DOCUMENTS
```

So, somehow I need the following commands, once fulfilled, to again apply to the next article, that will start again will  -->. But I just cannot get it to work the way needed. For example to extract 'The New York Times' in the partial html above I use, and it should automatically also been done to the 2nd/3rd/4th etc article.

```
journal = soup.find_all('span', class_='c2')[1].getText()
```

If anyone can point me in the direction I should start thinking it would be really appreciated!

*EDIT:*
Just to put more into perspective what I am trying to achieve. I can get the latter parts to work, but do not get it to check each article after the former.

```
For Each Article:
   * Determine Newspaper
      * If newspaper = x
              .
              .
              .
      * Else 
              Continue
```